# This puzzle design was a DISASTER!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

As any member of the PSE community knows, grid-deduction puzzles *really aren't* my forte.

In fact, I'd like to share one particularly disasterous attempt at designing a [Slitherlink](http://www.nikoli.com/en/puzzles/slitherlink/rule.html) puzzle.

---

***Disclaimer: This is a fictional story***

So, I was working on a slitherlink late one night, and when I woke up, I realised that my sleepiness had caused me to put some wrong numbers into the puzzle! I had only miscounted these clues by one, but they were wrong nonetheless.
I took a sip of coffee to wake me up, and then I noticed something interesting about the way I messed up the puzzle. I had gotten *exactly one* clue in every row and column misnumbered by one!
In my excitement in thinking that the puzzle was salvagable, I stood up, and accidentally tipped my coffee onto the puzzle!!!
This rendered some clues unreadable, and I couldn't remember if some of the now unreadable clues were the ones that were wrong or not.

After finishing my coffee, I realised that this was still a solveable puzzle.

[image]

There's my slitherlink puzzle, after being misnumbered AND having some clues (possibly correct, possibly misnumbered) destroyed by my morning coffee.

Can you find the intended answer to the slitherlink?

Comment: Looks fiendish...

Comment: Your coffee is remarkably selective in what it destroyed. What brand is that, I might want to try it :)

Comment: This is a very nice one! I hope you will post a 'making-of' post to see how you constructed it.

Comment: This is indeed a really great puzzle, I can only wonder what other new variations on grid puzzles you have in store.

Comment: @wl I'm glad you enjoyed it! I'm very busy (aren't we all, all the time?) but sometimes I have an idea I just really want to see come to life, and seeing a solver have a good time with a puzzle makes the work worth it :) when I next make a new grid puzzle, PSE will be the first to know :)

Comment: @elias when I get the time, sure!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The solved grid looks like this:

> [image]

The instructions assume a familiarity with solving normal Sliterlink puzzles. A dot next to a number means the clue is correct, a plus means the correct clue is higher, a minus means the correct clue is lower.

We start in the bottom left corner because a 0 and 3 can not be next to each other on the edge of the grid. This means the 1 and 3 in the same column have to be correct clues.

> [image]

If the 0 in the top row were correct it would lead to a loop, so it has to be a 1.

> [image]

This also means the first 3 in the third column has to be correct which means the 2 next to it can not be correct.

> [image]

The link can only go straight through that 2x2 area. If it would go horizontal, the top link would loop again.

> [image]

The 2 and 0 next to each other in the third row can not both be correct, so the last 0 in that row has to be.

> [image]

The 2 above that 0 can not be correct with the 3 around.

> [image]

Next we take a look at the 2 in the third row again. If that clue were correct the link would have to loop again.

> [image]

The 1 in the fourth column has to be correct, but the link also has to go through the bottom left corner. This needs 2 horizontal links in the three remaining possibilities leading to a link at the very bottom.

> [image]

The 2 and 3 in the fifth row have to be either 1 and 3 or 2 and 2. The clues 1 and 3 leave a dead end, so it has to be 2 and 2.

> [image]

This leaves only one clue to be incorrect in the last row.

> [image]

Noteworthy: The coffee only destroyed correct clues.

Comment: Nice! Also noteworthy: the incorrect clues have rotational symmetry :)

Comment: I'm quite pleased that your solving method is *exactly* the route I intended!

Comment: At first I used a slightly different route (7th step before 5th and 6th), but while creating the images I noticed that this route was actually easier.